# Group data within a one-dimension list using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use Angular and Bootstrap to represent a data grid and give user some control over it (edit data, etc.). The data set is array of objects, each object has a `group` property, which is not unique and represents what group a record refers to.

So, the dataset looks like

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    group: 'A',
    value: 'John'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    group: 'A',
    value: 'Jake'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group: 'B',
    value: 'Jack'
  }
]
```

I want Angular to output

```
<div class="row group">
  <div class="col-md-12">A</div>
</div>
<div class="row sample">
  <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">John
<div>
...
```

I tried `ng-repeat` but it only allows to fold arrays one into another, so the `{{ group }}` will be a top element and `{{ elementOfAGroup }}` will be its child. I need a final markup to be a plain set of DOM elements.

I googled for a solution but the only I've found were simple components (directives) that allow making up tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used custom "uniq" filter to accomplish this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.1.1/angular-filter.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="row group" ng-repeat="data in dataset | uniq: 'group'">
            <h3>{{data.group}}</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="child in dataset | filter: { group: data.group }">{{child.value}}</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angular.filter']);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.dataset = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    group: 'A',
                    value: 'John'
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    group: 'A',
                    value: 'Jake'
                }, {
                    id: 3,
                    group: 'B',
                    value: 'Jack'
                }
            ];

        }]);
    </script>
</html>
```

It may be slow with large data set.